# __Secure- prefix to cookies on phpmyadmin

Tags: security, cookies, phpmyadmin

Is the  __Secure- cookie prefix added by default on some/all cookies on the latest versions, or a feature / option to add in the configs?

I have noticed in the documentation that you have added a feature for SameSite cookies on a recent 5.x version but have found no reference to the secure __secure- cookie prefix.

I have only access to the older version 4.4 and have been able to add the __secure- text in front of the name of 3 of the cookies, by amending the files, but not the phpMyAdmin named cookie (the login cookie?). Any guidance?

Thank you
Martin

Checked out phpmyadmin documents and on web including stack overflow but found little info except that in general adding the prefix is recommended.

Comment: Adding characters to the cookie name is irrelevant to the behaviour. Are you asking about adding the secure **flag** to cookies? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: @symcbean No sir. My understanding is that the secure flag is the one at the end of the string (please correct if incorrect). . I am referring to the prefix. e.g.    __Secure-pma_lang=en; expires=Thu, 27-Jul-2023 14:47:44 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; secure; HttpOnly. cheers Martin

Comment: You are incorrect. The name of the cookie does not affect its behaviour - its the '; secure;' label on the value which makes it only passed via https

Comment: Sir, we talk at cross purposes. I entirely agree that the Cookie Prefix I referred to in my post only works when the secure flag is added. My question is not about adding that Secure flag - a given - but the official or recommended solution to add the actual Cookie Prefix to phpMyAdmin generated cookies.

Comment: NO THERE IS NO "PREFIX". What "official or recommended solution"? What is your expectation? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sir, developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies refers to the Cookie Prefix. Cheers. Martin

Comment: continuing - I am looking at how to modify the phpmyadmin code/ files to include the --Secure- or __Host- prefix options to the numerous Cookies generated by this application.. Cheers.

Comment: Answering my own question and as advised by @symcbean there is no default or otherwise option to add the cookie prefix ( __Secure-, __Host-) to the current releases/ master of phpmyadmin. Having looked at the current code it looks relatively straight forward to modify each reference to a cookie name to add the prefix. That would indicate to enabled browsers to reject any non secure (missing Https) access to a server. I will consider suggesting as a feature request.